# Chart JS Tooltip - place it in a fixed location outside the canvas

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I did a search and could not find an exact answer and I'm a bit of a newbie with ChartJS.

Right now I've got a chart that draws a vertical line on top of a line using an added plugin to ChartJS. My thought now is that I'm looking to make it so that the tooltip's value displays elsewhere not on the canvas. Pretty much I'm trying to recreate a Robinhood like experience.

[image: example]

I have the line and tracking already created. My only issue is that I want to have some text that displays the tooltip value and changes for each point. The red circle is what I'm looking to simulate for the tooltip. Instead of having it appear at the point, it should be fixed at a location and of course change values depending on the point.

I think I've read somewhere there is a method that can be used for ChartJS called getPointsAtEvent, but I'm not exactly sure how to properly use this, but if someone could help me, I'd be really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work out using customToolTips and using the tooltip.dataPoints.length. One issue I had when going through this though was that an error appears in the console when you go out of the canvas area, but doesn't stop anything from working.

I'm not exactly how to fix this one, but if anyone has encountered it, please let me know:

```
 (http://localhost:3000/Chart.js:10917:4)
dashboard:178 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at ChartElement.customTooltips (dashboard:178)
    at ChartElement.update (Chart.js:8660)
    at ChartElement.handleEvent (Chart.js:8952)
    at Chart.eventHandler (Chart.js:4679)
    at listener (Chart.js:4609)
    at HTMLCanvasElement.proxies.(anonymous)
```